# Extbase FAL file download

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have question about file download with Extbase and FAL.
I can render image with

```
<f:image src="{file.uid}" alt="" width='100' height="100" treatIdAsReference="1"/>
```

I can get image, but I also have PDF file for download, and I can't use this ViewHelper. 
Is there any other ViewHelper for file downloads?
If i dump that file i get this:

```
file => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReferenceprototypepersistent entity (uid=1342, pid=310)
         originalResource => NULL
         uid => 1342 (integer)
         _localizedUid => 1342 (integer)modified
         _languageUid => 0 (integer)modified
         pid => 310 (integer)
```

originalResource  is null for file, and for image, image is printed with that ViewHelper. And I can't get file...

Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the VHS viewhelper for that.
Check it out the following code:

```
<v:resource.file additionalAttributes="{foo: 'bar'}" data="{foo: 'bar'}" identifier="[mixed]" categories="[mixed]" treatIdAsUid="1" treatIdAsReference="1" as="NULL">
    <!-- tag content - may be ignored! -->
</v:resource.file>
```

Link to the documentation:
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Resource/FileViewHelper.html

You have to install the vhs extension and also to add the namespace on your template file.

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
```

As a last thing you should have the files indexed in typo3. For that create a scheduler task and select the File Abstraction Layer: Extract metadata in storage task.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the publicURL property of the originalResource to create a file link.

Sample Fluid to generate a list of files referenced in your domain model property

```
<ul class="download-list">
    <f:for each="{myObject.myFALproperty}" as="file" >
        <li><a href="{file.originalResource.publicUrl}">{file.originalResource.title}</a></li>
    </f:for>
</ul>
```

Just use the {myObject.myFALproperty} to see what you can access.

If you need more properties here are the basics of the Original and the reference in case you want to use the override located in the FlexForm

Original Attributes

```
filename :{myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.originalFile.name}
title:{myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.originalFile.title}
description:{myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.originalFile.description}
alt:{myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.originalFile.alternative}
uid:{myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.originalFile.uid}
path:{myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.publicUrl}
```

Reference Attributes

```
title: {myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.title}
description {myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.description}
```

Hope that helps.

Just for reference this is what the according TCA looks like, but you obviously already know that (note this sample has a maxitems setting of 10:

```
'myFALproperty' => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:xy_sample/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_xysample_domain_model_myobject.myFALproperty',
    'config' => 
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'myFALproperty',
        array('maxitems' => 10)
    ),
),
```

Comment: Link:{myObject.myFALproperty.originalResource.link}

Answer (score 3):

## Step 1/2

You can get the URI to the PDF file like this:

In your FLUID Template:

```
<f:uri.image src="{file.uid}" treatIdAsReference="1"/>
```

OUTPUT
    /path/to/your/pdf

This works even if "originalResource is null for file", like you stated in your question.

## Step 2/2

Create a link in your FLUID Template (using inline notation)

```
<a href="{f:uri.image(src:'{file.uid}', treatIdAsReference: 1)}">
Download PDF
</a>
```

## Test environment

- typo3 v7.6.19

Comment: Oh man, I do love wordpress. It is so much less complicated than typo3. And it achives the same things...